# Why does my repl java swing application doesn't work

Tags: java, swing, read-eval-print-loop

I've created a java swing repl program. You can check it out at this link:
https://repl.it/@Tomervx/MazeGame#Main.java
It worked pretty well before, but for some reason when I try to run it now, it only shows the "run your repl to see output" message in the console. I've searched around the internet, but I couldn't find any answer that worked. Is it a bug in my program, or a problem with repl?

Comment: I mean, when I press Run, the game starts

Comment: Wait a few seconds

Comment: What should the game do? When i run it, the game starts and prints a black square, should it continue and how do you control it?

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). (Not code at some link I won't, & some can't, follow.)

Comment: BTW - some things which work well in a console based environment do not translate well to a GUI. E.G. Lops often need to be replaced with the philosophy of the GUI reacting to events (button presses, action key on text fields or changes to the `Document` it encompasses..).

Comment: Code that draws on the screen should execute on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) (EDT)

Comment: For some reason, when I run it I don't get the black square I'm supposed to, I just get the 'run your repl to see output' over and over.

Comment: *"For some reason.."* Tip: Add @Abra (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.